# Why is my list not being populated?

Tags: prolog

For an assignment we are asked to write a predicate `route/3` that succeeds if there is a route from `Start` to `Finish`, visiting town in the list `Visits`.

I've come up with an idea for a solution but for some reason the `Visits` list is always empty after `route` terminates and I can't figure out why that is. I'm not looking for a solution to the question, just something to point me in the right direction.

Here is my code so far:

Note that my calls to `write` are simply for debugging reasons.

```
road('Wellington', 'Palmerston North', 143).
road('Palmerston North', 'Wanganui', 74).
road('Palmerston North', 'Napier', 178).
road('Palmerston North', 'Taupo', 259).
road('Wanganui', 'Taupo', 231).
road('Wanganui', 'New Plymouth', 163).
road('Wanganui', 'Napier', 252).
road('Napier', 'Taupo', 147).
road('Napier', 'Gisborne', 215).
road('New Plymouth', 'Hamilton', 242).
road('New Plymouth', 'Taupo', 289).
road('Taupo', 'Hamilton', 153).
road('Taupo', 'Rotorua', 82).
road('Taupo', 'Gisborne', 334).
road('Gisborne', 'Rotorua', 291).
road('Rotorua', 'Hamilton', 109).
road('Hamilton', 'Auckland', 126).

route(Start, Start, Visits) :-
    write(Visits), nl.

route(Start, Finish, Visits) :-
    write(Visits),nl,
    road(Finish, From, _),
    route(Start, From, [From | Visits]).

test :-
    Visits = [],
    route('Auckland', 'Wellington', Visits),
    write(Visits).
```

The output when running `test.`:

```
1 ?- test.
[]
[Palmerston North]
[Wanganui,Palmerston North]
[Taupo,Wanganui,Palmerston North]
[Hamilton,Taupo,Wanganui,Palmerston North]
[Auckland,Hamilton,Taupo,Wanganui,Palmerston North]
[]
true .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables in Prolog are *unified*, not *assigned*. Surely this argument is part of your course.

Then `Visits` in `test` keeps the empty list (the accumulator) you 'assigned' when start. You should add (or better, insert) an argument to `route`, that holds the built list. Something like

```
test :-
    route('Auckland', 'Wellington', [], Visits),
    write(Visits).
```